# Linux find files with similar name and move to new directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Say I have an unorganized directory with thousands of files that have prefix in their names like abc-tab, abc-vib, h12-123, h12-498.... How do I move files with the same prefix into their own directory?

I was thinking about using something like

```
find . -path '*/support/*abc*' -exec mv "{}" /new/abc\;
```

But this means I will have to retype the command for every prefix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grab all the prefixes with `ls` and `uniq` to get a single list, then move the files using a for loop.

```
for F in $(ls | cut -d- -f1 | uniq); do
    mkdir "${F}" && mv "${F}"-* "${F}"
done
```

Many people learn shell scripting from the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). Check out the [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) and [`uniq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq) man pages for details on those programs.

Comment: If I want to move the newly created folders to drive z would it be like this:
for F in $(ls | cut -d- -f1 | uniq); do
    mkdir "${F}" && mv "${F}"-* "${/z/F}"
done

Comment: Are you using cygwin? Then you would change the second line to `mkdir /cygdrive/z/"${F}" && mv "${F}"-* /cygdrive/z/"${F}"`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `for` loop to operate on each instance of each filename.

From within the directory containing the files:

```
    mkdir newfolder

    for i in prefix_*
    do
       cp $i newfolder/$i
    done
```

Then I'd check that the right files copied over, and if so run

```
    rm prefix_*
```

The more dangerous approach would be to run

```
    mkdir newfolder

    for i in prefix_*
    do
       mv $i newfolder/$i
    done
```

But mv will automatically remove the source files, and I like to ensure the correct actions happened before that.

Answer (score 0):

If the command basically does what you want you can simply wrap a script around it:

```
for i in abc h12 something_else
do 
  find . -path \*/support/\*${i}\* -exec mv "{}" /new/${i} +
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this script should work for you:

```
while read l
do
   prefix=${l%-*}
   mv "$l" "/new/$prefix"
done < <(find '*/support/')
```